Apply Picard-Lindelöf theorem to PDE?
For a known function $f$ I have the differential equation $\frac{d}{dt}u(x,t)=f(u,x,t,\frac{d}{dx}u(x,t))$. In this form I cannot apply the Picard-Lindelöf theorem (or the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem) to show uniqueness of a function $u$ satisfying above equation and an appropriate initial condition.
My idea is to rewrite $\frac{d}{dx}u(x,t)=\lim_ {h \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x+h,t)-u(x,t)}{h}$. For given $h>0$ I could apply the Picard-Lindelöf theorem to the system to get uniqueness.
Can't I use some continuity argument to show that my differential equation also has a unique solution?

Do you have that $f$ is locally Lipschitz in some topology? What topology are you interested in?

Yes, I am willing to assume that $f$ is locally Lipschitz (continuous in the norm topology).
